# Jenkins doesn't invoke psexec command, because "Access is denied"

Tags: jenkins, cmd, psexec

On our project we want to deploy our .Net application to remote machine. For that purpose we have chosen PsExec tool. The propblem is that the commands that work fine in `cmd` don't work in Jenkins. They look the similar way in Jenkins

```
bat '%windir%\\sysnative\\PsExec.exe \\\\ipaddress -u user -p password -accepteula -h cmd /c "command" /q"'
```

Jenkins prints that `Access is denied`, although it works well in `cmd`. Why should I do? How it works differently in Jenkins and cmd? Maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: Does your jenkins user have admin rigths to launch this command ?

Comment: See also the solutions proposed here: https://superuser.com/questions/540380/psexec-access-is-denied

Comment: @Algorys, yes, Jenkins service simply didn't have admin rights, so I logged onto my service as admin user and everything works fine. You can write your first comment as answer and I'll accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Jenkins service must be launched by an admin user. Then you'll have access to these commands.